# A query in binomial th. Based question

Tags: binomial-theorem

Posting the part of the solution...i know the concept on which it is asked but i got stuck while solving and i peeked into the solution, i found this

$=\frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)...4.3.2.1}{n!n!}x^n$                     **fine**
$=\frac{1.2.3.4...(2n-2)(2n-1)(2n)}{n!n!}x^n$                         **fine**
$=\frac{[1.3.5...(2n-1)][2.4.6...(2n)]}{n!n!}x^n$                     **fine**
$=\frac{[1.3.5..(2n-1)]2^n[1.2.3...n]}{n!n!}x^n$                       **2^n** is taken as common, i'm tricked here, n is raised to 2 which means there are n terms into $“[2.4.6...(2n)]”$ but how?
Please explain how there are n terms into that expression ($“[2.4.6...(2n)]”$)

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking; there is an equals sign with nothing before it.

Comment: While StackExchange is a Q/A site, more than just a question is expected from the asker. Try to focus your question to an actual and specific problem you have faced. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}
2×4×\cdots ×(2n)&=(2×1)×(2×2)×(2×3)×\dots×(2×n)\\
&=2^n×(1×2×\cdots×n )
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you .....i got it